# Cleaning up empty sessions in django side effects

Tags: django, session

I am already familiar with django's management command `clearsessions`, But we had some legacy logic in our code base that used to create `session` objects for all the visitors - if they did not have a previous session value assigned to them. It was for A/B testing purposes (We had to fix the test for each user and figured the session key would be a good value for this usage)

The problem is now that we have gotten rid of this redundant session creation logic, we have ended up with something around 180 million `empty` session records.

```sh
$ echo NjU3ODI5ZTg5MDY0OWE1YzYzNTczMzEzM2ExMGQ4NTI4ODNlZGFiNTp7fQ== | base64 -d
$ 657829e890649a5c635733133a10d852883edab5:{}
```

Obviously this `session_data` is an empty session.

```py
In [9]: Session.objects.filter(session_data="NjU3ODI5ZTg5MDY0OWE1YzYzNTczMzEzM2ExMGQ4NTI4ODNlZGFiNTp7fQ==").count()
Out [9]: 175163446
```

Now you can see that we have something around 180 million records associated with this `session_data`.

**Question**

Are there any side effects regarding deletion of these empty sessions? I can not think of any problems occurring to any of our users.

Any insights or clarifications would be appreciated.

Comment: The only side-effect is that you may force people to log in to your application again

Comment: Why is that? I am deleting sessions that have absolutely no data associated to them. So none of them should concern logged in users. @IainShelvington